# Is there a way to identify whether the user is using Lightning Experience or classic?

Tags: lightning-experience

Is there a way to identify whether the user is using Lightning Experience or classic? I have been using "`UserInfo.getUIThemeDisplayed()`" and it used to give me value of "Theme3" for classic and "Theme4d" for Lightning Experience. Now it is giving me "Theme3" for both. Is there any other attribute which helps me determine the Lightning Experience Vs Classic. Winter '17 Salesfroce

User in Lightning Experience.

Apex Code.

```
system.debug(UserInfo.getUIThemeDisplayed());
system.debug(UserInfo.getUITheme());
```

System Debug,
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify how your apex code is being invoked? For example, using Lightning Out in Visualforce page that is rendered in Lightning Experience will still say the displayed theme is Classic because the context is the Visualforce page, not the one/one.app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a bug to me although I have not tested it myself. Try opening case with support on this.

The other way would be to look for sforce.one context variable using JavaScript .Inside lightning experience context variable Sforce will be true.

```
var isSF1 = typeof sforce !== 'undefined';
```

Comment: `var isSF1 = typeof sforce !== 'undefined'`